# Save objectForKey from NSDictionary to NSString from Objective-C code to Swift 2.0

Tags: swift

How can i convert Objective-C code to Swift 2.0

```
project_id = [self.record objectForKey:@"id"];
```

where self.record is NSDictionary and project_id is NSString.
Please help i am new to Swift

Comment: I think you meant "String" instead of "NSString"...?

Comment: Don't use `NS(Mutable)Dictionary` / `NSString` in Swift. Use native `Dictionary` / `String`

Comment: @Ahmad F you are correct it is String

Comment: NSDictionary *statuses;
            self.lblprojectname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", statuses=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"name"]]; how can i convert it into swift 2.0 any help

Comment: What error? Swift  Dictionary (`[String:AnyObject]`) requires key subscription `record["id"]`, `objectForKey:` is not supported.

Comment: It gives error 'NSMutableDictionary?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Comment: Once again, don't use `NSMutableDictionary`. Swift `Dictionary` as `var`iable is mutable.

Comment: @vadian Could you answer                                                           
NSDictionary *statuses; self.lblprojectname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", statuses=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"name"]]; how can i convert it into swift 2.0 any help

Comment: jsonDict is ... NSDictionary*jsonDict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:kNilOptions error:&error];    .... if have used this code in objective c project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer can be more complex because Swift needs the right type, but basically

```
project_id = self.record["id"]
```

if record is declared as Dictionary of Strings. If it is declared as dictionary of AnyObject it would be

```
project_id = self.record["id"] as? String
```